# C++ saveFileDialog in VS. How to use saveFIledialog to save into existed file?

Tags: winforms, visual-c++

I'm using boolean with `if-else` statements to give two options, one creates a new file if it has not been saved and another save over existed file if it has been saved.

```cpp
private: System::Void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(System::Object ^ sender, System::EventArgs ^ e) {
  bool save = true;
  if (save == true) {
    saveFileDialog1 - > Title = "";
    saveFileDialog1 - > DefaultExt = "*.txt";
    if (saveFileDialog1 - > ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK) {
      FileStream ^ f = gcnew FileStream(saveFileDialog1 - > FileName, FileMode::Create);
      StreamWriter ^ w = gcnew StreamWriter(f);
      //write lines
      w - > Close();
    }
  } else {
    saveFileDialog1 - > Title = "";
    saveFileDialog1 - > DefaultExt = "*.txt";
    if (saveFileDialog1 - > ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK) {
      FileStream ^ f = gcnew FileStream(saveFileDialog1 - > FileName, FileMode::OpenOrCreate);
      //String filePath =.FileName;
      StreamWriter ^ w = gcnew StreamWriter(f)
      //write lines
      w - > Close();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is the problem?

Comment: I want to save like Microsoft word. When we first save, it will  save as new file but then after we add more texts, it will saved without showing a dialog. But i dont know how to do it because after I add more texts, it still saves as a new file, not to the same file.